# Faster calculation of complex functions

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw some complex functions using `pgfplots`.  The problem is that drawing takes really a lot of time, especially some of sub-functions are repeated (calculated several times).  For example

```
0.165*sin(2*x)-0.128*sin(x+5616/73)
cos(23.44*sin(x))
```

appear on several positions.

Is there any way to optimize calculation and make drawing faster?

Thanks for suggestions.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\def\anga{47} % latitude
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \i in {-4,-3,...,4}{%
  \addplot[domain=0:360,samples=60] ({180+asin(cos(23.44*sin(x))*sin(15*(\i+0.165*sin(2*x)-0.128*sin(x+5616/73)))/sqrt(1-(sin(\anga)*sin(23.44*sin(x))+cos(\anga)*cos(23.44*sin(x))*cos(15*(\i+0.165*sin(2*x)-0.128*sin(x+5616/73))))^2))},{asin(sin(\anga)*sin(23.44*sin(x))+cos(\anga)*cos(23.44*sin(x))*cos(15*(\i+0.165*sin(2*x)-0.128*sin(x+5616/73))))});
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a table maybe?

Comment: @percusse That is the last resort solution that I want to avoid.

Comment: You can `declare function` alternatively that uses arguments as in the manual of TikZ

Comment: Will this help, since function shall be evaluated over and over again?

Comment: Well it has to be evaluated anyhow at least the common terms would be evaluated once in the recusrion (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Well I defined the long function and now it evaluates even slower

Comment: You can also use Lualatex as demonstrated in [this article](http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/numerical-methods-luatex.pdf). If I have time I will try an example with your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank all contributors for their answers.  In the end I decided to go for the classical solution by calculating the curve points in Python and import them.  (I actually wrote the program in the way that output of code can be inserted directly in .tex, thus avoiding having another outside table.)

If any more elegant solution appears later, I will accept it instead of mine.

Answer (score 9):

Letting `gnuplot` do the calculations may be a lot faster. For this case the pure `pgfplots` code typically took just over 5s on my machine, while the `gnuplot` version took between 0.5s and 0.6s.

It does of course require that `gnuplot` is installed, and one has to compile with `shell-escape` enabled, e.g. `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\def\anga{47} % latitude
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \i in {-4,-3,...,4}{%
\addplot [black] gnuplot [raw gnuplot,id = p\i, mark=none] {
set parametric;
set trange [0:360];
set samples 60;
set angles degrees;
fx(t) = 180 + asin(cos(23.44*sin(t))*sin(15*(\i+0.165*sin(2*t) - 0.128*sin(t+5616/73)))/sqrt(1-(sin(\anga)*sin(23.44*sin(t)) + cos(\anga)*cos(23.44*sin(t))*cos(15*(\i+0.165*sin(2*t) - 0.128*sin(t+5616/73))))^2));
fy(t) = asin(sin(\anga)*sin(23.44*sin(t)) + cos(\anga)*cos(23.44*sin(t))*cos(15*(\i+0.165*sin(2*t) - 0.128*sin(t+5616/73))));
plot fx(t),fy(t)
};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
anga=47 --  latitude
function sindeg(x)
    return math.sin(x*math.pi/180)
end
function cosdeg(x)
    return math.cos(x*math.pi/180)
end
function plot_curve(i)
    local N=60
    tex.sprint("\\addplot[line width=1pt,black] coordinates {")
    for theta=0,360,360/N do
        fct1=0.165*sindeg(2*theta)-0.128*sindeg(theta+5616/73)
        fct2=cosdeg(23.44*sindeg(theta))
        x=180+180/math.pi*math.asin(fct2*sindeg(15*(i+fct1))/math.sqrt(1-(sindeg(anga)*sindeg(23.44*sindeg(theta))+cosdeg(anga)*fct2*cosdeg(15*(i+fct1)))^2))
        y=180/math.pi*math.asin(sindeg(anga)*sindeg(23.44*sindeg(theta))+cosdeg(anga)*fct2*cosdeg(15*(i+fct1)))
        tex.sprint("("..x..","..y..")")
    end
    tex.print("};")
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \i in {-4,-3,...,4}{%
    \directlua{plot_curve(\i);}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since Lua uses angles in radians, I had to redefine the sine and cosine functions in radians. It's then very fast.

Of course you should compile it using `lualatex` command.

Comment: Should that last `tex.print` be `tex.sprint` like the others?

Comment: `tex.sprint` prints a string to LaTeX, and `tex.print` prints the string plus a newline. That's why the last is `tex.print`, because the line is complete.

Comment: If I got it right, it is essentially like writing a program, but in LaTeX.  It was kind of easier for me write a python code and also optimized it to neglect points that might fell out of the plot.  Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: Yes; the only advantage of LuaLaTeX is that all the code is in the same file; the disadvantage, that the points are calculated each time you recompile the document.